# Dataflow flex template execution fails due to proxy (connection timed out) issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm following GCP's official guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) on building and running flex templates. After building the template and storing in GCS, I'm attempting to executing it however, after a few minutes of being in the `Queued` status, the job fails with the following log message:

```
2021-11-25T15:35:16.888799175ZError occurred in the launcher container: Template launch failed. See console logs.
```

In the console logs stored in the GCS file: `gs://{bucket_name}/staging/template_launches/2021-11-25_07_28_47-8896068131466144656/console_logs` , I see the following lines:

```
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:31:07.908528","line":"exec.go:38","message":"Executing: python /dataflow/template/test-beam.py --requirements_file=/dataflow/template/requirements.txt --project={project_name} --job_name=test-beam --subnetwork={subnetwork_name} --region=us-west1 --service_account_email={service_account_email} --input_pubsub_topic={topic_path} --runner=DataflowRunner --template_location={gcs_path} --staging_location={gcs_path} --temp_location={gcs_path} --no_use_public_ips"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.092313","line":"exec.go:66","message":"Traceback (most recent call last):"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122711","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py\", line 89, in check_output"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122814","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    out = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122829","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py\", line 411, in check_output"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122843","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    **kwargs).stdout"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122854","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py\", line 512, in run"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122871","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122889","line":"exec.go:66","message":"subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', '/dataflow/template/requirements.txt', '--exists-action', 'i', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1."}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122913","line":"exec.go:66","message":"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122931","line":"exec.go:66","message":"Traceback (most recent call last):"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122941","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/dataflow/template/test-beam.py\", line 130, in \u003cmodule\u003e"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122954","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    run()"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122962","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/dataflow/template/test-beam.py\", line 127, in run"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122973","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    p.run().wait_until_finish()"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122985","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py\", line 549, in run"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.122997","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    self._options).run(False)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123007","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py\", line 573, in run"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123019","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123030","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py\", line 466, in run_pipeline"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123049","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    artifacts=environments.python_sdk_dependencies(options),"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123060","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/environments.py\", line 806, in python_sdk_dependencies"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123073","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    skip_prestaged_dependencies=skip_prestaged_dependencies)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123086","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/stager.py\", line 224, in create_job_resources"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123099","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    setup_options.requirements_file, requirements_cache_path)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123110","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py\", line 253, in wrapper"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123122","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    return fun(*args, **kwargs)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123133","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/stager.py\", line 645, in _populate_requirements_cache"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123146","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    processes.check_output(cmd_args, stderr=processes.STDOUT)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123159","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py\", line 97, in check_output"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123172","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    .format(traceback.format_exc(), args[0][6], error.output))"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123187","line":"exec.go:66","message":"RuntimeError: Full traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123198","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py\", line 89, in check_output"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123210","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    out = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123222","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py\", line 411, in check_output"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123233","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    **kwargs).stdout"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123252","line":"exec.go:66","message":"  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py\", line 512, in run"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123264","line":"exec.go:66","message":"    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123275","line":"exec.go:66","message":"subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', '/dataflow/template/requirements.txt', '--exists-action', 'i', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1."}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123295","line":"exec.go:66","message":" "}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123306","line":"exec.go:66","message":" Pip install failed for package: -r           "}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:54.123323","line":"exec.go:66","message":" Output from execution of subprocess: b\"WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa55f253d50\u003e, 'Connection to proxy-web.{company_name}.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/\\nWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa55f230810\u003e, 'Connection to proxy-web.{company_name}.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/\\nWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa55f2308d0\u003e, 'Connection to proxy-web.{company_name}.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/\\nWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa55f230c50\u003e, 'Connection to proxy-web.{company_name}.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/\\nWARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\u003cpip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa55f230e90\u003e, 'Connection to proxy-web.{company_name}.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/\\nERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)\\nERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy\\n\""}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:55.082639","line":"exec.go:52","message":"python failed with exit status 1"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:55.082698","line":"launch.go:77","message":"Template launch failed: exit status 1"}
{"container_id":"1235ff25ce0b6a36aff4cf0fd8de5b60a84b2b63dfebe8527f42bc09bf2c064e","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/11/25 15:32:55.082719","line":"launch.go:99","message":"Uploading console logs to gcs location: gs://{bucket_name}/staging/template_launches/2021-11-25_07_28_47-8896068131466144656/console_logs"}
```

The error seems to be occurring at the execution of the command:

```
/usr/local/bin/python -m pip download --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r /dataflow/template/requirements.txt --exists-action i --no-binary :all:
```

The Docker image being used in the template is built using the following `Dockerfile` where I set both the proxy and pip config to use the company certificate:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY test-beam.py .

# Do not include `apache-beam` in requirements.txt
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/test-beam.py"

# Setting Proxy
ENV http_proxy=http://proxy-web.{company_name}.com:80 \
    https_proxy=http://proxy-web.{company_name}.com:80 \
    no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,.{company_name}.com,{company_name}.com,.googleapis.com

# Company Cert
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl http://{company_name}.com/pki/{company_name}%20Issuing%20CA.pem -o - | tr -d '\r' > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{company_name}.crt \
    && curl http://{company_name}.com/pki/{company_name}%20Root%20CA.pem -o - | tr -d '\r' > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{company_name}-root.crt \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge curl \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set pip config to point to Company Cert
RUN pip config set global.cert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Install apache-beam and other dependencies to launch the pipeline
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U -r ./requirements.txt
```

Two things make me believe the proxy and certificates are configured correctly in the above Docker image:

1. The `pip install` commands in the image above run successfully when
   building the image.
2. When I attempt to execute the same command, i.e.
   `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip download --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r /dataflow/template/requirements.txt --exists-action i --no-binary :all:` in a locally running container of the image used in the Flex
   template, it executes without any errors.

Would anyone know the cause of the errors when executing the Dataflow job and how can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed this part of the error message? `ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy` Wondering might point us to the root of the problem.

Comment: I did, but what could be the cause for not being able to find numpy?

Comment: Yeah no idea. I'm hitting the exact same problem as you. I'll keep you posted and if you fix it I'd love to hear about it. Thanks!

Comment: I have removed numpy and pandas from `requirements.txt` and now the pipeline is running! All stages failed but at least the job kicked off.

Comment: Looks like I'm having to remove `scipy` from `requirements.txt`, whereas `numpy`, `setuptools`, etc are fine.